Derivative of Linear Model with respect to Residual
I am looking at two sections on the wikipedia page for total least squares, specifically:
#Allowing_observation_errors_in_all_variables and #Example
I have two questions, the first is how does one take the derivative of a linear
model with respect to the residuals, and second, in the specific equation on the wikipedia page, is $K_{X}$ a vector or a matrix?
Here is a screenshot of the two sections:


So my first question is Equation 1 (my annotation) in the example supposed to be equation 3 in the description?  Once I have the formula according to equation 3 for the example, how do I take it's derivative with respect to the residuals to get $K_{X}$ and $K_{Y}$ and are these vectors or matrices?

$K_y$ and $K_x$ are in general matrices, but they can be diagonal matrices, and thus isomorphic to vectors.
Consider the simple case of only one predictor $x$ with independent measurement errors: $\tilde{x}_i=x_i+r_{x,i}$, and i.i.d noise. Then $y_i+r_{y,i}=\alpha+\beta(x_i+r_{x,i})+\epsilon_i$, thus $f(\vec{r}_{y},\vec{r}_{x})=\alpha\vec{1}+\beta(\vec{x}+\vec{r}_{x})+\vec{\epsilon}-\vec{r}_{y}$, and:
$$
\begin{aligned}
K_y=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\vec{r}_{y}}f(\vec{r}_{y},\vec{r}_{x}) &= I,\\
K_x=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\vec{r}_{x}}f(\vec{r}_{y},\vec{r}_{x}) &= -\beta I,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. Then we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
M &= K_yM_yK_y^\top+K_xM_xK_x^\top = I\times (\sigma^2_yI)\times I^\top+ (-\beta I)(\sigma^2_xI)(-\beta I)^\top\\
&= \sigma^2_yI + \beta^2\sigma^2_x  I =\operatorname{diag}\left(\sigma^2_y+ \beta^2\sigma^2_x \right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Now consider a case of non-independent errors: there are four measurements of $x$ and $y$: two from one source sharing the same measurement errors $r_x,r_y$, and two from a different source sharing the same measurement errors $r_x',r_y'$. Then, applying matrix calculus in denominator layout, one gets:
$$
\begin{aligned}
K_y=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\vec{r}_{y}}f(\vec{r}_{y},\vec{r}_{x}) &= \left[\begin{array}{cccc} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\  
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right],\\
K_x=-\frac{\partial}{\partial\vec{r}_{x}}f(\vec{r}_{y},\vec{r}_{x}) &= -\beta\left[\begin{array}{cccc} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\  
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right],
\end{aligned}
$$

Just to double check, in your second example with four measurements, M_x=sigma_x^2*[row1=1,1,0,0,
row2=1,1,0,0,
row3=0,0,1,1
row4=0,0,1,1] and the same respectively for M_y?

Well, $M_x$ is the covariance matrix of observations $\tilde{x}$, which is not diagonal anymore but given by the entries $(M_x)_{i,i}=\operatorname{var}(\tilde{x}i)=\sigma^2_x$, $(M_x){i,j}=\operatorname{cov}(\tilde{x}i,\tilde{x}j)=\sigma^2{s}$ if $i,j$ come from the same source $s$ and $=0$ otherwise. This is just an illustrative example, because it is not possible to estimate $\sigma^2{s}$ with only two measurement per source.

Why in the first example is Ky an nxn square Identity matrix but then in the second example, it's dimension shrinks from (4x4) to (2x4)? (assuming we had 4 data points in both examples)

In the first example, where measurement errors are independent, we have one per measurement (4 errors $\times$ 4 measurements). The second one is just a simple example of non-independent measurement errors, where 2 are shared between four measurements (2 errors $\times$ 4 measurements). The matrix $K_y=-\frac{\partial}{\partial r_y}f(r_y,r_x)$ is the (negative) derivative of a vector with respect to another vector, so it has dimensions $(\operatorname{dim}, r_y \times \operatorname{dim}, f)$.
